# How between-graph replication with asynchronous updates in Tensorflow runs?

Tags: asynchronous, parameters, tensorflow, worker

**We focus on this situation: between-graph replication with asynchronous updates.**

[The following figure](https://github.com/tensorflow/ecosystem) shows how it works. And I known that each worker will send gradients to every ps and receive its updated parameters from every ps.(Is it correct? Is it path 1 and path 2?)

**But can anyone explain in detail what does the figure 1,2,3,4,5,6 mean respectively?**

Thank you in advance!

[image: between-graph replication with asynchronous updates]

Comment: briefly, "ps" and "worker" are both workers, and their interface is defined by [protobuf/worker_service.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/143f6d77dcf419f1d36fb9cb4d7e4624eea0bdcd/tensorflow/core/protobuf/worker.proto), "master" is defined by [protobuf/master_service.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a304537954a865752ad1b18461e6bd67b36082db/tensorflow/core/protobuf/master_service.proto), those files give more details